# Use an Amelia object as input for a Mokken Scale Analysis

Tags: r, dataframe

I have run multiple imputations using R's Amelia package and would
like to use the imputed dataset to analyse Mokken Scale Analysis.
But mokken requires the object to be a data frame. I tried
as.data.frame(x) and as.matrix(x) but it says that it cannot coerce
class amelia into a data frame or matrix.

```
 australia93=as.data.frame(australia93)
 Error in as.data.frame.default(australia93) :
 cannot coerce class '"amelia"' into a data.frame

 coefH(australia93)
 Error in check.data(X) : Data are not matrix or data.frame
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means that R does not know how to cast the `amelia` object to a `data.frame`. Even if you succeed in getting the `amelia` object to a data.frame, the Mokken scale analysis routine probably expects its data in a very specific form. You need to look at what `amelia` offers, and what Mokken needs, and provide a translation between them.

Without more information (particularly a reproducible example), it is hard to help you more than this.